# Move all open Firefox tabs into a bookmark folder

Tags: firefox-extensions

I have about 50 tabs open and would like to create a folder in the bookmarks and bookmark all those tabs at once and add them to that folder.

Is this possible with a trick? or maybe an add-on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click in a tab,

1. select **"Select All Tabs"**
2. select **"Bookmark Tabs..."**

The form that pops up will let you create a folder.

Comment: What would that be on Firefox for Android?

Comment: @raph82 I do not think there's one like that for mobile app yet.

Comment: @raph82 you could sync your tabs to a desktop firefox instance and bookmark them there